# How I can reduce the unnecessary space between header and item using android leanback

Tags: java, android, leanback

I am using android leanback for android Tv application, want to reduce unnecessary space between header and it's items.

As I attached the image for better understand.
[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please advice me.

Comment: This issue can be resolved by using leanback library version 23.0.1. The space increases when leanback version  25.1.0 is used. So Try using version 23.0.1 of leanback library

Comment: try adding these values in dimens.xml

<dimen name="lb_browse_expanded_row_no_hovercard_bottom_padding">0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="lb_browse_expanded_selected_row_top_padding">4dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="lb_browse_selected_row_top_padding">0dp</dimen>